# can not enter password on Windows 8 log-on page- Business domain

Tags: windows-8, login

I am new here, I tried searching to see if there was a similar question and I could not find any. I hope this has not been asked before.

I have a laptop from my old job, that I got to keep after I left the company. On that laptop I have an account on the business domain. I am still using that laptop for personal matters and have not had any problem for 2 years. Today I had an issue, that when I was restarting my computer, I was not able to type anything out in the password box. the mouse was working, but nothing on the log on page seemed to be active (including restart button). If I reboot and start the laptop using the safe mode I don't have this issue. But even after restarting many times the issue persisted. I finally made a local account without a password in safe mode to see if I can log on, I had first the same issue (freezing on the logon page), but that finally worked and I was able to switch user. My question is, does this problem have anything to do with the business domain? Or is it unrelated? How should I resolve it? I appreciate any help!

Comment: "does this problem have anything to do with the business domain?' - Is your inability to type your password connect to the fact you are no longer connected to domain, it absolutely does not, that sounds like a hardware failure.  If you are unable to log into the account after 2 years, that absolutely is relevant, but you didn't mention that fact.

Answer (score 1):

Make a new non-domain user account. Undoubtedly, Work (old job) did some cleanup and removed your old account.

So in terms of accounts, just start fresh.

Once you have a local account and once it is all working (check to be sure), you can delete the domain account and profile.

I assume (after 2 years) this machine is not domain-connected.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I did make a local account. Do I need to delete the account on  the business domain? Will it cause any problem if I remove it?

Comment: Once the local account is stable, yes you can delete the domain account and it should not cause problems. I made that note in my answer.